# Converting DHCP to static on ubuntu 12.0.4

Tags: dhcp

I am trying to set up a static IP address for my new Ubuntu server.

I have been trying to do some research and found information that got me started on [this reference page](http://www.mariusv.com/ubuntu-linux-convert-dhcp-network-configuration-to-static-ip-configuration/).

One thing that was different for me. When I use the GUI to set up an internet connection. I select eth2 then I was connected to the internet using a DHCP IP.

When I converted the IP now I no longer have access to the internet unless I use the connection established by the GUI.

Here is what I have done
`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

I changed the existing info to

```
iface eth2 inet static
address <static ip>
netmask <mask>
gateway <gateway IP>
```

then I edited this file
`sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf`

I added both of my DNS Server ips

then after saving the file I have done
`sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

I get the following error
RTNETLINK answer: File Exists
Field to bring up eth2

I have tried to change the Ethernet card number to eth1 and then to eth0 but still getting the same error.

What can I do to correct this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe before restarting your network try `sudo ip link set eth2 down` also I myself have not had to go any further than putting the proper contents in `/etc/network/interfaces` to get a static ip address...

Comment: Thanks Jacob. That did not work. I tried to shutdown all 3 ethernet ports. why it is working only with eth2 for the DHCP? why it chose that one and not eth0?

Comment: Actually that did work. I had to turn down all 3 of them then use eth2 in the config file. That worked.  thanks a lot :)